# Which data type cane be used in .net to map a variable in oracle VARCHAR2(100)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I would like to know the data type that need to be used in Asp.net C# to map a variable which is having type VARCHAR2(100)  in Oracle
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here;

[What is the difference between VARCHAR, VARCHAR2 and CHAR data types?](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_varchar_varchar2_and_char_data_types)

Both CHAR and VARCHAR2 types are used to store character string values, however, they behave very differently. The VARCHAR type should not be used:

Based on this, use a String in c#.

Answer (score 0):

hi VARCHAR2(100) is a string of length of 100 
you can use it as regular string variable

Answer (score 0):

Max is right, but beware if you writes your values back in the DB. They will be trimmed up to 100 characters due the max lenth of your field (100)